# Setting a Compiler Flag Xcode

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

is it possible to set a compiler flag in Xcode to not compile any source code which is flagged not into the archive (ipa)?!

Maybe just like an if-statement?!

```
if (shouldBeInAppPackage)
{
    //Code in here should be compiled in App Package
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pre-processor macro for that.  In the pre-compiled header, or some other header file which is imported into the source files you want to use this on, you can define:

```
#define INCLUDE_IN_BUILD 0
```

and then wrap code with:

```
#if INCLUDE_IN_BUILD
    code();
    code();
#endif
```

You can then selectively include/exlude that code by changing the `0` to `1`.

Think of a better name than `INCLUDE_IN_BUILD`, however.

Comment: So Code inside that #if statement is not in the Build!? or is it in the build but will not executed?

Comment: @chrizstone It will be included if `INCLUDE_IN_BUILD` is non-zero or excluded if `0`.